# How to predict next item based on historical data with LSTM Keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have historical visualizations on ecommerce of each user. As I want to predict the next item to be visualized (at really I want to predict next 10 items visualized, but I'm trying to begin with more simple model), I have transformed each item to an unique integer. Now items are encoded to unique indexes 0, 1, 2, ..., num_unique_integers.
**Question 1**: Should I begin the indexes with `1`?

Some users views 10 items, others views 2 items, others viewed 5 items...So the timesteps are different for each user.

Suppose that user 1 has viewed these items (encoded as indexes):

```
[3, 10, 230, 1, 222, 98]
```

And I know in the future he will view this item:

```
[65]
```

Now suppose user 2 viewed these items:

```
[5, 10, 12]
```

And I know in the future he will view this item:

```
[3]
```

So I'm right padding every user to has the same length.
I'm masking with `-1` because I starter indexes from `0`.
**Question 2**: Should I start indexes from 1 and mask these missing timesteps with `0`?

Supposing that I can mask with `-1`, user 2 items now are:

```
[5, 10, 12, -1, -1, -1]
```

I have no `nan` in sequences and I right padded every user in the correct format.
To the training data I have `177182` users. As I will use `LSTM` from Keras to build a many-to-one sequence model, I reshaped every user to 3D shape. This is what `X_train` looks like:

```
[[[1818554]
  [1818554]
  [1488094]
  ...
  [     -1]
  [     -1]
  [     -1]]

 [[1003556]
  [1496514]
  [ 444647]
  ...
  [     -1]
  [     -1]
  [     -1]]

 [[ 394651]
  [ 708912]
  [  36967]
  ...
  [     -1]
  [     -1]
  [     -1]]

 ...

 [[1216588]
  [1216588]
  [1216588]
  ...
  [     -1]
  [     -1]
  [     -1]]

 [[ 149401]
  [ 331973]
  [  97939]
  ...
  [     -1]
  [     -1]
  [     -1]]

 [[1628493]
  [ 339106]
  [1553924]
  ...
  [     -1]
  [     -1]
  [     -1]]]
```

X_train shape: `(117182, 18, 1)`
**Question 3**: This is the right shape? I'm using `18` timesteps to each user, and just `1` feature.
**Question 4**: What `1` feature here means? I think that means that I have only information of the sequence to predict next item. If I would like to incorporate metadata's item (like category, or price) it would be `2` features or `3` features?

This is what `y_train` looks like:

```
[[[1845675]]

 [[ 915969]]

 [[ 574660]]

 ...

 [[1450189]]

 [[ 179777]]

 [[1125658]]]
```

y_train shape: `(117182, 1, 1)`
**Question 5**: This is the right shape for the target? I will output only `1` item for eery user by now.

Now let's begin the model:

```
# number of timesteps 
timesteps = 18

# masking value
MASKING = -1

# number of unique items (-1 because the masking value)
unique_items = len(item2idx_mapping.keys()) - 1

model = Sequential()

# masking empty timesteps
model.add(Masking(mask_value=MASKING, input_shape=(timesteps, 1)))

# LSTM layer with 18 time steps and one feature
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(timesteps, 1)))

model.add(Dense(unique_items))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is the model summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
masking_7 (Masking)          (None, 18, 1)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_7 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               40800     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 2102276)           212329876 
=================================================================
Total params: 212,370,676
Trainable params: 212,370,676
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I'm using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` because my classes are integers (indexes).
As I understood, the `Dense()` layer will output `2102276` (num_unique_items) probabilities, and the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` will use the max value to find the class (in this case, an integer representing the item index)

**Question 6**: Should I use `categorical_crossentropy` here and one-hot my data? I have `2102277` unique items on my data.

**Question 7**: My `Dense` layer is right? I will output only one item from each user. If I would like to output the top-10 items, what `Dense()` should looks like?

So now let's to the fit part:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=1, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), verbose=1)
```

In the beginning oth the preprocess data, I splitted in train, validation and test sets in the right format (that's ok for me). That's why I'm passing `validation_data` here.
This is what looks `X_val`:

```
array([[[1246829],
        [1223718],
        [1246829],
        ...,
        [     -1],
        [     -1],
        [     -1]],

       [[1372502],
        [     -1],
        [     -1],
        ...,
        [     -1],
        [     -1],
        [     -1]],

       [[ 290857],
        [ 590159],
        [ 590159],
        ...,
        [     -1],
        [     -1],
        [     -1]],

       ...,

       [[1049576],
        [1049576],
        [1049576],
        ...,
        [     -1],
        [     -1],
        [     -1]],

       [[ 486021],
        [ 785693],
        [ 486021],
        ...,
        [     -1],
        [     -1],
        [     -1]],

       [[1314096],
        [1314096],
        [1314096],
        ...,
        [1267549],
        [2075858],
        [2075858]]])
```

And this is what looks `y_val`:

```
array([[[1868124]],

       [[ 846133]],

       [[ 332563]],

       ...,

       [[2071300]],

       [[1457682]],

       [[ 790620]]])
```

The final shapes are:

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_val.shape)
print(y_val.shape)
(117182, 18, 1)
(117182, 1, 1)
(3859, 18, 1)
(3859, 1, 1)
```

**Question 8**:  Am I passing `X_val` and `y_val` in the right way?

This is what I get when training.
I'm not using GPU, but I will use:

```
Epoch 1/10
33/117182 [..........................] - ETA: 30:00:00 - loss: 14.90 - accuracy 0.000e+00
```

**Question 9:** Should I use `accuracy` here as metric? As I understood the metric is only for investigate my model after the training. This doesn't influence the training epochs.

**Question 10:** Why is loss big? It should not be between `[0, 1]`? Or it will decay after so many epochs?

**Question 11:** As my data are big, do you think there's another way to compute more fast (I can use GPU). But without considering GPU, what could I do? Can I use more batches in training, like `batch_size=64`?

---

After this long explanation, please, let me now if I said something wrong!